# Migrating from DD-WRT to Tomato

Tags: networking, router, firmware, dd-wrt, tomato

Is it possible to switch to the latest version of Tomato on a router that's already running DD-WRT?  Using the default Linksys firmware on my WRT54GL v1.1, I had to upload a micro version of DD-WRT first.  I imagine that, since I'm now running third-party firmware, I won't have to do that again to make the switch, but I thought I should check so as not to brick it.

This router is taking a back seat to a new AirPort Extreme (for the 'n' capability), but I still want to have the soon-to-be-Tomato device sit between the AirPort Extreme and my modem for the superior traffic graphing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it's possible. If DD-WRT's firmware uploader balks at you for some reason, the (Windows only) TFTP method should handle it.

Comment: TFTP Uploading a Firmware works just as well on Mac OS X and Linux. There are plenty of how-tos to google.

From my experience it was always easy to just reflash a WRT54GL from DD-WRT to Tomato-WRT. Since both store their settings in NVRAM routers usually even keep their settings.
Be sure to flash over an ethernet cable and not over WiFi if easily possible, makes flashing more reliable.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  Just wanted to double-check before I had a paperweight with antennae on my hands.

Comment: There are several choices for TFTP servers in Linux - I went with one that seemed pretty easy enough.  The fiddly part is the same on Windows and Linux - setting everything to have the particular IP address required, and making sure the filename and directory name are exactly correct to the letter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I migrated from DD-WRT to Tomato. Specifically, I changed DD-WRT v24 to Tomato (Version 1.28 by shibby). I did this on a Linksys E2500 (hardware revision 1).

1. Perform a [30/30/30 reset](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Hard_reset_or_30/30/30) to reset DD-WRT to its default settings. (In retrospect, if one wants to preserve their DD-WRT settings, a reset is not required.)
2. Record the username and password the router uses. (Should be admin/root.)
3. Download the correct firmware for your router. For Shibby's firmware, it seems to be hosted [here](http://tomato.groov.pl/download/K26RT-N/build5x-128-EN/Linksys%20E-series/). I downloaded **tomato-E2500-NVRAM60K-1.28.RT-N5x-MIPSR2-128-Max.bin**. Depending on the version number and router model, you'll have to use the bar at the top of the page to navigate to the firmware you want.
4. Update the firmware through the DD-WRT web interface. Browse to the firmware file on your computer and upload it to the router.
5. Wait for it to finish. I waited 10 minutes before I did anything with the router. It seemed to be stuck in DD-WRT mode after that. (It identified itself as DD-WRT, and none of my passwords worked.)
6. Reset the router using the reset button on the router. This is the same button used for the 30/30/30 reset. I was paranoid that I would brick my router, so I waited around 45 minutes between uploading the firmware and performing this router reset. I held the reset button for 5 seconds.
7. The router should now be running the default configuration for Tomato. If not, unplug it and plug it back in.